# Android v1.5 w/ browser data storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, offline, jstore

I'm trying to build an offline web application which can sync online if the network is available. I tryed [jQuery jStore](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jstore/) but the test page stop at "testing..." whitout result, then I tryed [Google Gears](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_database.html) which is supposed to be working on the phone but it is not found.

```
 if (window.google && google.gears)
 {
  google.gears.factory.getPermission();

  // Database
  var db = google.gears.factory.create('beta.database');
  db.open('foobar');
  db.execute('create table if not exists Lectures' +
           ' (ID_COMPTEUR int, DATE_HEURE timestamp, kWh float, Wmax float, VAmax float, Wcum float, VAcum float);');

 }
else
{
alert('Google Gears non trouvé.');      
}
```

the code does work on Google Chrome v5.

**[edit]**

`alert(window.google);` on the phone is undefined, but is an object in Chrome.

`alert(google.gears);` does nothing on the phone and jam the javascript, but is an object in Chrome.

**[edit 2]**

in the phone configuration, gears is activated.

**[edit 3]**

to be clear, you have to use google.gears database on Android 1.5, and html5's localStorage on Android 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! "gears_init.js" wasn't loading correctly. My code was using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="gears_init.js"></script>
```

whitout having the file locally. I downloaded the file from google and now it works.
I don't know why it was Chrome working correctly on chrome..